# ON/OFF screen detecting (in Android API 22-27)

Tags: java, android, service, screen

I'm making an app that tells you how much did you work with your Android device in your day. So I set something like stopwatch but I don't know how to stop it when the Screen goes OFF and how to resume it when Screen turns ON. (even if the app is completely closed)

Comment: Run foreground service with Broadcast Receiver for `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF` and
`android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON`.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I'm new at Android
please tell me what to do , step by step